# How to create "or" inputs?

Tags: python

How do I specify "or" in a Python program I'm trying to create? I'm trying to create a Python program that outputs information based on inputted information.

I want to allow a person to enter either one of these pieces of information in-order to give an output from a data frame.

Here is what I have so far (not correct):

```
enter_city = input("Enter City: ") or enter_zip_code = input("Enter Zip Code: ") or enter_state = input("Enter State: ")
... other code ...
print("Nearest Cupcake Location: " + ... other code ...)
```

How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to ask the user to "Enter location (city, zip, or state)" and then infer state if the uppercased input is in the list of valid two-letter states, infer a zip code if the input is all numeric, and infer city otherwise.

Comment: `input` returns a `str`, with no semantic connotations about what that string represents. Just because you *expect* `enter_city` to be a city name doesn't mean the user couldn't have entered a ZIP code instead. Likewise, the prompt is just informative text for the user; it has no effect on what actually gets returned by `input`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. "I want to allow a person to enter either one of these pieces of information in-order to give an output from a data frame." First off, if the user is entering this information **in order**, then how is there any question of "either"? First, the user enters the city, then the zip code, then the state, correct? Or what exactly are the intended steps?

Comment: If you *do* want the user to be able to input the values out of order, then there are many aspects of this that you need to think about first. For example: if you *don't know* which thing the user will type first, then what should the first prompt look like? Then: *what are the rules* you want to use, in order to decide whether that input is a city, state or zip code? Then: depending on what was entered, what pieces of information remain? How will you prompt for them? **What should the program do** if the user tries to, say, input a ZIP code twice?

Answer (score -1):

How about using

```
location = input("Enter City or ZIP Code: ")
```

And then in your `... other code ...` checking whether the input includes numbers (or your specific ZIP code format) and treating it as ZIP code, or as a City otherwise? You can use regex for a special ZIP code format or if you know that the ZIP codes always include numbers (which they do in my country), then you can just check if the input includes a number.

Comment: Please read [answer] and note that this is **not a discussion forum**. It is the asker's responsibility to figure out the intended control flow; we don't *design* how the program will work, because that is pure code-writing. It can't help anyone else with the same question, because other people *can't have* the same question. Please refrain from answering until a proper question is available.

Comment: (Keep in mind that OP apparently also wants to distinguish city names and state names.)